# How do you prove that $dy/dx=e^{xy}$ is a seperable differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do you prove that $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{xy}$ is a separable differential equation?

In my textbook, it says that $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{xy}$ is indeed a separable differential equation but gives no proof for it.

Note: A separable differential equation is one which the terms of $x$ are on one side and those of $y$ on the other side. E.g-$(3y)dy=(x^2)dx$ is a separable differential equation whilst $(x)dy=(3y)dx$ is not.

I have tried writing $e^{xy}= (e^x)^y$ but I couldn't separate the $x$ and $y$ terms further from this. I can see no other pathway. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Perhaps that it is a typo and the equation actually is $\frac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx}=e^{x+y}$.

Comment: @josecarlossantos-Could be, so does that mean that dy/dx=e^(xy) is definitely not a differential equation?

Comment: It is a differential equation because it contains the differential term $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but it is not separable as it cannot be written in the form $f(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)$.

Comment: source/proof??? of not being seperable

Comment: @ShashwatTomar Your last comment doesn´t sound very polite.

Comment: @ShashwatTomar I don't know, but I strongly suspect that it is not separable.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry if I sounded rude

Comment: You can reduce this to something like $\frac{dt}{dw} = w^t$ where $w=e^x$ and $t=y-1$. I think this should help you know if it's separable.

Comment: Actually, the second example of your note *is* separable:  $\frac{dy}{3y}=\frac{dx}{x}.$

Comment: If $\frac{dy}{dx} = h(x,y)$ is separable then $h(x,y) = \frac{g(x)}{f(y)}$ would imply $h(x,y) h(x',y') = h(x,y') h(x', y)$ but $h(x,y)=e^{xy}$ does not satisfy that condition - for example, $h(1,1) h(2,2) = e^5$ but $h(1,2) h(2,1) = e^4$.